# Syntax Error inside typedef const struct

Tags: c, mplab

I'm trying to create a const  struct usign  using the name of each parameters.

```
    typedef const struct {


  uint8_t RegisterNumber;   

}StaticParameters;

StaticParameters MenuRegisters[2] = 
{
.RegisterNumber=1,
.RegisterNumber=1
};
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `MenuRegisters` is an array. You can't just pull out some subfield of it's elements in the initializer.

Comment: Sorry i couldnt found answer with link above

Comment: The linked question itself has the correct syntax...